# overflow-x not working and only few columns are displaying on the screen

Tags: html, angular, css

The below is the css used for my table. I have 15 columns. Even though I use overflow-x: scroll, it is not having any effect on the table and is displaying only half of the columns on the screen. Can anyone help on this?

```html
.table {
  font-family: Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
  //width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
  min-width: 150px;
  font-size: small;
}
   
.table th {
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="rule-container mat-elevation-z20">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" style="background-color: #a8b4c6">
    <div fxFlex="85" fxLayoutAlign="center">
      <p class="rules-class"><b>RULES</b></p>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="15" fxLayoutAlign="flex-end">
      <mat-icon class="close-table" (click)="closeMe()">close</mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <table class="method-rules-table">
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
  ---
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let element of dataSource2" [style.color]="element.rowColor">
     <td style="min-width: 250px;">Row1</td>
     <td>Row2</td>
     <td>Row3</td>
    <td>Row4</td>
    <td>Row5</td>
     ----
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also post the html

Comment: I added. I simplified the HTML while posting. I have around 15 columns to display. I used Angular material table (mat-table) before but it has a problem with not displaying the line between the rows when I added the horizontal scrollbar. So I'm started implementing the normal table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `table-layout` to fix the width and height of your table to the `.table` class. And then wrap the table with a table container for scroll bars.

Now your`.table` class will become

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Have a outer container like `.table-container`

```
.container {
  overflow:scroll;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
```

}

Working link: http://jsbin.com/kutokabojo/edit?html,css,output